# two SUMs and two GROUP BYs

Tags: mysql, group-by, sum

I have a select-query that is like this, that gives correct results:

```
SELECT SUM(value) AS "sum1" FROM table GROUP BY id1, id2
```

Now I want a second sum with another group by condition like this, that gives correct results, too:

```
SELECT SUM(value) AS "sum2" FROM table GROUP BY id1
```

But how can I build **one** select query, that gives me both sums?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do something like this:

```
SELECT t1.sum1, t2.sum2
FROM 
(select sum(value) as sum1 from table group by id1, id2) as t1
join 
(select sum(value) as sum2 from table group by id1) as t2
```

But since you have different groups the results will provide duplicate values for sum1... don't know if that's useful.

Comment: You are right, it is very ineffective to produce duplicate values. I tried a group_concat of sums like the following query, but as expected `GROUP_CONCAT` doesn't work with `GROUP BY`:

`SELECT SUM(value) AS "total", GROUP_CONCAT(SUM(value) GROUP BY id1, id2) FROM table GROUP BY id1`

Comment: OK, your solution works and my question has been answered. But I will look for another solution, that will fit to my problem better.